# Spring boot(ec2) + S3: Bucket does not exist error

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I created a project that works with S3 using Spring boot. It worked fine in both local and other deployment environments (cloudtype), but an error occurred that the bucket did not exist in the ec2 environment.

I checked several times for typos. It still works well with the same bucket in different deployments.

Gradle dependency -> implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.2.6.RELEASE'

S3 Service

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class S3FileServiceImpl implements MyFileService{

    private final AmazonS3 amazonS3;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.s3.bucket}")
    private String bucket;

    @Override
    public UploadFile uploadFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String originalFilename = file.getOriginalFilename();
        String storeFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
        metadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());

        amazonS3.putObject(bucket, storeFileName, file.getInputStream(), metadata);
        return new UploadFile(originalFilename, storeFileName);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
cloud:
  aws:
    s3:
      bucket: ${PROD_S3_BUCKET}
    credentials:
      access-key: ${PROD_S3_ACCESS_KEY}
      secret-key: ${PROD_S3_SECRET_KEY}
    region:
      static: "ap-northeast-2"
      auto: false
    stack:
      auto: false
```

Error message: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: {SECRET}; S3 Extended Request ID: {SECRET}; Proxy: null)

Comment: Is your bucket region set to ap-northeast-2?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Java V1 which is not best practice. I recommend upgrading to [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html). AWS SDK for Java V2 works fine with a Spring BOOT app and S3. For your issue, make sure that the EC2 instance has access to the bucket. See this link for more information - https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket